# Why does WebRTC use TURN sometimes?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, stun, turn, ice-protocol

I've written a small WebRTC demo that streams a video file to the other peer and everything works fine (it's a real P2P connection without using the TURN server) except for this:

One client connects via a mobile network and one via wifi. When the mobile client creates the offer and kicks off the ICE candidate back-and-forth, they settle on srflx candidates and create a real P2P connection.

But when the wifi-client creates the offer, they fall back to the TURN server as a relay.

This happens in Firefox and Chromium on Ubuntu.

1. Does this behavior point to an obvious problem in my code?
2. If not, how can this be? Shouldn't the ICE protocol produce the same two candidates no matter which client is the controller?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59485045 specifically the part about how STUN doesn't work with all NATs. That may be the reason why. I'm not sure of the exact points where they are incompatible so that may be the overall answer.

Answer (score 3):

NATs have two attributes influence if a connection will succeed between two WebRTC Agents. Those attributes are `filtering` and `mapping`.

---

When you send a packet to an address outside your NAT you create a `mapping`. A mapping is your `IP:Port` and people usually call it your `Public IP`. This is the `Public IP` that others can send into. A STUN server is just an echo server that responds with your mapping.

The first mapping type is an `Address Independent` NAT. This is the one you want. In this configuration you re-use a `mapping` everytime you contact an IP outside your NAT. You can give out your `mapping` to remote peers and they can send to you.

The second mapping type is `Address Dependent`. In this configuration you create a new `mapping` for each remote address. This means that the IP/Port you got back from the STUN server can NOT be used by other peers. In this case you may have to use a TURN server.

---

`filtering` controls who is allowed to send in. Some NATs allow anyone to send traffic in. Like `mapping` behavior this is called `Address Independent`. Other NATs only allow someone to send traffic in that you have attempted to contact, knows as a `Address Dependent` NAT.

---

Check out [WebRTC for the Curious's Connecting Chapter](https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/03-connecting/) I try to explain this in more depth. Pion also has a tool [stun-nat-behavior](https://github.com/pion/stun/tree/master/cmd/stun-nat-behaviour) that prints out the details of your NAT like so.

```
connecting to STUN server: stun.voip.blackberry.com:3478
=> NAT mapping behavior: endpoint independent
=> NAT filtering behavior: address and port dependent
```